# Failed to load configuration files in docker container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, containers, configuration-files

i have a microservice application written in Go. Each service has a Dockerfile and config file in their directories. Here's the structure of my project https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvelM.png. When i start a Dockerfile of each service it works correctly, the container loads the config data from copied directory and runs successfully, but if i want to run the whole project using docker compose it fails with an error (can't load the config file bcs he can't get access to the file inside the container). Let's take a look at one of the services Dockerfile and config. [There is a dockerfile of astroService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HC7Z.png), and a config file and config location [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixoeJ.png).[Docker compose 1 part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSIVp.png)
[docker compose 2 part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETNkW.png)

I tried to fix this using volumes. I mounted the directory with config file into the container, but it also doesn't work. I need to run the project using docker compose, idk maybe there is some problems with context or something...